# Is there a webservice/API to grab a screenshot/thumbnail of a PDF online?

Tags: php, web-services, api, pdf

I have tried a number of screencapping services but none so far can cap a PDF and make a thumbnail.

I have also seen scripting for this purpose but it all relies on installing Ghostscript and ImageMagick and this app will be on a shared server and it does not have them installed.

Admins of the site will be uploading new PDFs constantly and want to have thumbnails of page one displayed.  Anyone seen a webservice that can produce these?

Comment: instead of trying to work around your hosts limitations, move host or move to a vps, and install anything you like.

Comment: I've not used [this](http://convertapi.com/) but it might be worth a shot (found by searching for [convert pdf to image api](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=convert+pdf+to+image+api)). @Dagon's right though - if your host isn't up to scratch, move to another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably really change your (shared) hosting to one where at least ImageMagick's *convert* is available:

```
convert -scale '600x600+0+0>' some.pdf[0] some_thumb.png
```

Working around such limits is hard and paying a few bucks more (or even the same amount somewhere else) is most certainly worth the effort of switching.

Comment: Thank you.  I have discussed with them and the move will be scheduled.  Much obliged!